# python paramiko: Permission denied

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, permission-denied

I have a sftp program called transmit. I use it to access a sftp server. I log in with username, password and everything works fine. I can delete, create and see everything.

Now I must access this sftp server with a python script. Therefore I installed parmiko. I set up everything as in the demo file but I strangly get the error message permisson denied:

```
hostname = "123.456.789.1"
port = 22

hostkeytype = None
hostkey = None
try:
    host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
except IOError:
    print '*** Unable to open host keys file'
    host_keys = {}

if host_keys.has_key(hostname):
    hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]
    hostkey = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
    print 'Using host key of type %s' % hostkeytype

t = paramiko.Transport( (hostname, port) )
t.connect( username="customUser", password="xyzpasswd", hostkey=hostkey, pkey=None )
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
print sftp.listdir() # <- works
sftp.get("~/myfolder/test.png",".", None ) # <- permission denied error
t.close()
```

And this is the output if I run it:

```
Using host key of type ssh-dss
['.ssh2', 'archiv', 'myfolder']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 539, in <module>
main()   
File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 531, in main
ladeDatenVomSFTPServer()   
File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 493, in ladeDatenVomSFTPServer
sftp.get("~/myfolder/test.png",".", None )
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 606, in get
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 245, in open
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 635, in _request
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 682, in _read_response
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 712, in _convert_status
IOError: Permission denied, file: ~/myfolder/test.png
```

This all works fine in Transmit but with parmiko it fails. What did I wrong?

Comment: How are you running the script? Does ~/myfolder exist? Does the user account running the script have write access to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second argument should be a filename, instead of a dot `.`

Replace

```
sftp.get("~/myfolder/test.png",".", None )
```

with something like

```
sftp.get("~/myfolder/test.png","~/test.png", None )
```